# Simple Table Server in jMeter 5.0 special characters

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

im using Simple Table Server in jMeter 5.0 for reading data from csv

1. I have this line in jmeter.properties: sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8
2. In HTTP request i have set Content Encodig to UTF-8
3. Input csv file has set encoding UTF-8

But in Response Data in View Result Tree i get for example this kind of characters "HornĂ˝ HriÄŤov" instead of "Horný Hričov"

In jMeter 4.0 this setting works i only upgrade to 5.0 and use my existing Test Plan

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you detail how you configured each part ? Thanks

Comment: 1.  i think its clear, 2. in standard HTTP Request Sampler i fill Content Encoding to UTF-8 and 3. with PSPad i have set encoding of file to UTF-8

Comment: I mean can you please show some screenshot :-) because I need to see your configuration

Comment: hope this will help

https://imgur.com/sPyIuH6
https://imgur.com/mcdiSwL
https://imgur.com/3GtaocC
https://imgur.com/Aj439Jm